# Insert the last argument in bash in vi mode without inserting a leading space

Tags: bash, readline, vi-mode

Using bash in the default (emacs) mode I get the following behavior when I hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>**.**</kbd>.

```bsh
$ echo hello
hello
$ hello  # I hit `<ESC>.` to insert this
```

Note there is no space before the word `hello` that is inserted when I hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>**.**</kbd>.

If I switch to vi mode and configure `.` I do get a leading space:

```bsh
$ set -o vi
$ bind -m vi-command ".":yank-last-arg
$ echo hello
hello
$  hello  # I hit `<ESC>.` to insert this. Note the leading space.
```

Is there any way to configure bash/readline to avoid this leading space?

Comment: This bug (assuming you agree it's a bug) is fixed in recent versions of bash. I don't get a leading space in 5.1.4. I'm not sure when exactly it was fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That really looks like a bug, but actually Bash is just trying to follow [the POSIX specified](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html#tag_20_117_13_05) behavior of `_`,

> [count]_
> Append a <space> after the current character position and then append the last bigword in the previous input line after the <space>. Then enter insert mode after the last character just appended. With a number *count*, append the *count*th bigword in the previous line.

As a workaround, add this to your `~/.inputrc`. You can change the `\M-h` to some other unbound key if you want.

```
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi-command
"\M-h":history-expand-line
".":"a!$\e\M-hA"
```

Now, open a new terminal. Upon striking <kbd>.</kbd> in normal mode,

- `!$` is insterted in the command-line.
- `\e` (means <kbd>Esc</kbd>) goes back to normal mode.
- `\M-h` triggers `history-expand-line` action, which expands `$!` to the value of the last argument.
- `A` moves to the end-of-the line and enters insert mode.

```
$ echo "X Y Z"
X Y Z
$ "X Y Z" #<ESC>. inserts this
```

```
$ echo "X Y Z"
X Y Z
$ cat "X Y Z" #cat <ESC>. inserts this
```

Answer (score 0):

When I insert something, and then enter Command mode, the cursor moves left *as if* it were deleting the space after the last word typed, but when I then re-enter edit mode, and insert something else the space following the last char of the last word of the previous insert is restored.

Adding a space manually is what generates the double space.